# Task 'clean;' is not in your gulpfile in Windows with Node v0.10.26

Tags: node.js

I am having a gulpfile.js in my node project which has clean task written to it.
But on doing npm start I am getting the error: Task 'clean;' is not in your gulpfile
And says in the package.json, It fails in the line:

Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    gulp clean; gulp dist; node app.js

Any pointers will be a help.

Comment: I am having the same issue..an answer would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Ash,

Can you provide your gulpfile.js?

Typically, this means you don't have the following:

```
gulp.task('clean',function() {
    // do something here.
} );
```